# Apple certificates installation issue in mac runners (GitHub Actions)

Tags: macos, github-actions, keychain, codesign, code-signing-certificate

I am currently setting up the build process of my project on GitHub Actions with a macOS runner (macos-12 / macos-13). As part of the process, I need to install the "Developer ID Application" and "Developer ID Installer" certificates on the runner for codesign purpose.

While doing this I came across [Link to the article 1](https://twocanoes.com/trusting-certificates-in-system-keychain-without-prompting/).

To automate the certificate management, I followed the steps mentioned in this article: [Link to the article 2](https://localazy.com/blog/how-to-automatically-sign-macos-apps-using-github-actions). The article provides a solution for trusting certificates in the system keychain without prompting.

However, I encountered an issue while trying to set the custom keychain as the default one in the runner. The following error message is displayed:

```
Will not set default: UID=0 does not own directory /Users/runner
security: SecKeychainSetDefault: Write permissions error.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

[See error pic here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3aSs.png)

This error prevents me from proceeding with the workflow, and I'm unable to set the custom keychain as the default one on the runner.

I'm open to any guidance or alternative approaches to successfully install and trust the certificates in the keychain on the macOS runner.

[Github Issue Link](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/issues/7947)

https://localazy.com/blog/how-to-automatically-sign-macos-apps-using-github-actions